# Installing gcc on a Mac 10.9

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

installing gcc on a mac. everything worked fine until I got to the terminal command:
sudo port select -set gcc mp-gcc48

I get the following error:
Usage: port
[-bcdfknopqRstuvy] [-D portdir] [-F cmdfile] action [privopts] [actionflags]
[[portname|pseudo-portname|port-url] [@version] [+-variant]… [option=value]…]…

“port help” or “man 1 port” for more information.

Can you offer any help?

- See more at: http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/08/how-to-install-gcc/#comment-23281

Answer (score 1):

The `--set` option is not actual needed here, but if you include it should be preceded by **two** hyphens:

```
sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc48
```

MacPorts gives you much better feedback if you start it in interactive mode and then type in the required commands:

```
hostname:~ username$ sudo port
MacPorts 2.2.1
Entering interactive mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
[Users/username] > select gcc mp-gcc48
Selecting 'mp-gcc45' for 'gcc' succeeded. 'mp-gcc48' is now active.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing with Homebrew http://brew.sh

Install Homebrew, update, make sure the brew doctor is happy, then run:

```
brew tap Homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
```